# Finding limit points of a set in $R^2$

Tags: general-topology

The given set is

> $$S:=\left\{\left(m+\frac{1}{2^{|p|}},n+\frac{1}{2^{|q|}}\right): p,q,m,n \in \Bbb Z\right\}$$

I can't understand how to obtain its derived set. I needed an intuitive approach rather than a theoretical one as I am a new learner and needed a basic idea first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $(m,n)$ and note that as $p,q\to \infty$, points from $S$ can get as close to $(m,n)$ as you'd like.

Also note that a small enough neighbourhood around any $(x,y) \in S$ contains no other points of $S$.

Comment: Just a question, "a small enough nbd around (x,y) doesn't contain other points of S" as you stated.. I got a bit confused can you please elaborate on this for my clarity.

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha It means that for $(x,y) \in S$ I can find $r>0$ such that $B((x,y),r) \cap S = \{(x,y)\}$ in a more formal statement. But the fact should be obvious from drawing a few points from $S$. A more proof requires a bit more work.

Comment: Thank you.. it helped